# Kivy buildozer docker: No buildozer.spec found in the current directory. Abandon

Tags: python, docker, kivy, buildozer

Having built a buildozer Docker based on the instructions on https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/, I try to run it and get an error:

```
kivyproject $ ls
main.py
buildozer.spec
setup.py
[...]
kivyproject $ docker run --volume "$(pwd)":/home/user/hostcwd buildozer android debug
# Ensure build layout
No buildozer.spec found in the current directory. Abandon.
```

Also, I find an empty directory was created next to `kivyproject` called `kivyproject;C`.

What is going on?

I'm running on Windows from a Git bash shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that Docker the string passed to `--volume` wasn't auto-translated by the Git bash shell to a Windows path, so Docker expected this:

```
--volume "c:\...\kivyproject:/home/user/hostcwd"
```

but got this:

```
--volume "/c/.../kivyproject:/home/user/hostcwd"
```

The solution was wrapping `pwd` with `cygpath -w`:

```
kivyproject $ docker run --volume "$(cygpath -w $(pwd))":/home/user/hostcwd buildozer android debug deploy
```

It was a good idea to share the cache too, so as not to re-download the SDK and NDK every time:

```
kivyproject $ docker run --volume "$(cygpath -w $HOME/.buildozer)":/home/user/.buildozer --volume "$(cygpath -w $(pwd))":/home/user/hostcwd buildozer android debug deploy
```

To troubleshoot this, I changed the last line of the `Dockerfile` from `ENTRYPOINT ["buildozer"]` to `ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]` and then I could run `docker run --volume [...] -it bulldozer`, get a shell and see that it was seeing an empty directory. Then I noticed a directory was created outside next to my working dir called `workingdirname;C` and suspected cygwin path shenanigans.